# Filtering Nested Properties in ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my controller I have:

```
$scope.currentDiscount = new DiscountPrototype;
```

Where:

```
var DiscountPrototype = function(){
    this.Id                     =   0;
    this.PromoCode              =   null;
    this.DiscountValue          =   null;
    this.DiscountProducts = []
}

var DiscountProductPrototype = function(discountId,id,catId,catType,name) {
    this.DiscountId             =   discountId;
    this.ProductCategoryType    =   catType;
    this.Name                   =   name
}
```

And then I push a bunch of new DiscountProductPrototypes into the DiscountProducts array of $scope.currentDiscount. If the DiscountProduct has a ProductCategoryType = "C" it is a category, and if it is "P" it is a product. My filter is intending on only displaying the objects in the DiscountProduct array that are categories.

```
<div ng-repeat="category in currentDiscount.DiscountProducts | filter:{category.ProductCategoryType: 'C' : true}"
     class="productTile">
  <p>{{category.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

With the above filter I get the following error:

```
Syntax Error: Token '.' is at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].
```

Which seems to say there's something wrong with:

```
category.ProductCategoryType
```

If I do the following, I get no error, but the filter does nothing. Both categories and products are displayed.

```
<div ng-repeat="category in currentDiscount.DiscountProducts | filter: category.ProductCategoryType='C'" 
     class="productTile">
```

Do I need to create a custom filter to achieve this kind of filtering?

Comment: `filter:{'ProductCategoryType': 'C' : true}`

Comment: Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

Comment: To help with syntax checked responses, try providing a plunker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```html
<div ng-repeat="category in currentDiscount.DiscountProducts | filter:{ProductCategoryType: 'C'}"
     class="productTile">
  <p>{{category.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks DeborahK, and to everyone else who contributed to solving this issue!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with placement of `true` word.
`true` must be placed after second colon. After first colon, it should be just `Expression`.

Try following...

```
<div ng-repeat="category in currentDiscount.DiscountProducts | filter:{ProductCategoryType: 'C'}: true"
     class="productTile">
  <p>{{category.Name}}</p>
</div>
```

For more information on Filters, refer: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter

Comment: Syntax Error: Token '' {1} at column {2} of the expression [{3}] starting at [{4}].

Comment: Try removing the : true part. You are filtering where ProductCategoryType : 'C', correct?

Comment: ng-repeat="category in currentDiscount.DiscountProducts | filter: {ProductCategoryType: 'C'}" Worked. @DeborahK Do you want to create an answer with your solution so that I can mark it as accepted?

Comment: `true` must be placed after second colon. After first colon, it should be just `Expression`.